# Is there an intuitive explanation for $ x^2+y^2=7 z^2 $ doesn't have any integer solution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As we all know that $x^2+y^2=z^2$ has infinite integer solutions. Can we use this fact to give an intuitive explanation for $ x^2+y^2=7 z^2 $ doesn't have any integer solution? $x, y, z $ are positive integers and $(x,y)=1$

Comment: Isn't $x=y=z=0$ a solution?

Comment: Oh, sorry. $x, y, z$ are positive integers and $(x,y)=1$

Comment: @wxlu, Could you edit your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imagine you have a solution $(x,y,z)$ with $x$ and $y$ relatively prime. Then if you reduce modulo $7$, you find $x^2 + y^2 = 0$ in $\mathbf{F}_7$. If $x$ or $y$ is $0$ so is the other, meaning that $7$ divide $x$ and $y$ which is impossible as they are relatively prime. Then you have $(x/y)^2 = -1$ in $\mathbf{F}_7$ which is impossible as $-1$ is not a square in $\mathbf{F}_7$, as $\mathbf{F}_7$'s squares are $0, 1, 2$ and $4$. Remark : I noted by abuse $x$ and $y$ the images of $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbf{F}_7$, hope it doesn't cause confusion.

Comment: That is neither a answer to the question ("Does this fact ...")  nor does this  give us a complete answer to the more usefull question: what are the integer solutions of the equation.

Comment: Read the question again, and then read my answer again, and convince yourself that my answer is an answer to the question. The intuitive reason is that $-1$ is not a square in $\mathbf{F}_7$. If you find that your question (knowing integer solutions of the equation) is more useful, either ask it, or convince yourself that its answer results *trivially* from the answer to the initial question.

Comment: The real point is not $x$ and $y$ being relatively prime or not, but being both divisible by $7$ or not. If $7$ doesn't divide $x$ and $y$ gcd, then $-1$ would be a square in $\mathbf{F}_7$. If $7$ does divide $x$ and $y$, take out from then the biggest power of $7$ dividing them and see what happens to the equation... something like $7^{2d} ({x'}^2 + {y'}^2) = 7 z^2$ with $d\in\mathbf{N}^{*}$. What could you say then ?

Comment: I still I can't see where you use the fact that $x^2+y^2=z^2$ has infinite integer solutions.

Comment: Try harder to see. According to values of $d$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $x^2+y^2 = 0 \pmod 7 \to x = y = 0 \pmod 7$. Then use Descending method.

Answer (score 3):

Reduce mod $4$.

$x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0,1,2 \bmod 4$

whereas

$7z^2 \equiv 3z^2 \equiv 0,3 \bmod 4$.

So if there were a solution both sides would have to be $0 \bmod 4$, hence all three of $x,y,z$ would be even, contradicting the coprimality assumption.

Answer (score 2):

For your problem, we use the result: if $p$ is a prime of the form $4k+3$ and $p|x^2+y^2$, then $p|x,p|y$ (use Fermat theorem to prove this).

More generalizing result: the equation $x^2+y^2=nz^2$ has root different from $(0,0,0)$ ($x,y$ need not to be relatively prime) if and only if each of the prime factor of the form $4k+3$ of $n$ has an even exponent.